# How to Avoid Exponential Value(2.0E+7) in VF Email Template?

Tags: formula-field, vf-email-template

I have designed VF Email template inwhich when I closed an opportunity,it sends notification email to owner of record.
Below is the VF page that I designed:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Opportunity {!RelatedTo.Name} Closed as {!if(RelatedTo.StageName ='Closed Won','Won','Lost')}"  recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<html>
    <body>

    <P>Hi,</P>
    <P>The following opportunity has been Closed as {!if(RelatedTo.StageName ='Closed Won','Won','Lost')} with the following details. Kindly review the same. <br/>

       Opportunity Name: {!relatedTo.Name} <br/>
       Opportunity Owner: {!relatedTo.Owner.Name} <br/>
       Opportunity Stage: {!relatedTo.StageName} <br/> 
       Account Name: {!relatedTo.Account.Name} <br/>
       Total Value: {!relatedTo.TotalValue__c}<br/> 
     </p>
    </body>
</html>

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>

</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Total Value is a Formula field of type currency.It contains value as USD **20,000,000.00**. When I receive an email template,it displays the value like this **2.0E+7**.

How can i avoid exponential value here.I want to display the exact value as USD 20,000,000.00 in Total value field.
Can someone please tell me what should I modify here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you are working but they are making interesting deals :D

If you want your amount to be formatted as currency you should use:

```
Total Value:<apex:outputText value="{0, Number, Currency}">
                <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.TotalValue__c}" />
            </apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.I have modified like this <apex:outputText value="{0, Number}">{!relatedTo.CurrencyIsoCode} &nbsp; Now it gives expected result if I am using different currency.